# gcc compiler error: stl_construct.h

Tags: c++, gcc

I have a C++ source file FileLogger.cpp that includes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>                    << line 23
#include "FileLogger.h"
```

With gcc 4.8 on Ubuntu 14.04, this file results in compiler error:

```
Compiling /mnt/c/<snip>/FileLogger.cpp
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/vector:62:0,
                 from /mnt/c/<snip>/FileLogger.cpp:23:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_construct.h: In instantiation of ‘void std::_Construct(_T1*, _Args&& ...) [with _T1 = std::basic_ofstream<char>; _Args = {std::basic_ofstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >}]’:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:75:53:   required from ‘static _ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_copy<_TrivialValueTypes>::__uninit_copy(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _InputIterator = std::move_iterator<std::basic_ofstream<char>*>; _ForwardIterator = std::basic_ofstream<char>*; bool _TrivialValueTypes = false]’
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:117:41:   required from ‘_ForwardIterator std::uninitialized_copy(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _InputIterator = std::move_iterator<std::basic_ofstream<char>*>; _ForwardIterator = std::basic_ofstream<char>*]’
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:258:63:   required from ‘_ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_copy_a(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator, std::allocator<_Tp>&) [with _InputIterator = std::move_iterator<std::basic_ofstream<char>*>; _ForwardIterator = std::basic_ofstream<char>*; _Tp = std::basic_ofstream<char>]’
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:281:69:   required from ‘_ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_move_if_noexcept_a(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator, _Allocator&) [with _InputIterator = std::basic_ofstream<char>*; _ForwardIterator = std::basic_ofstream<char>*; _Allocator = std::allocator<std::basic_ofstream<char> >]’
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/vector.tcc:556:42:   required from ‘void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_default_append(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type) [with _Tp = std::basic_ofstream<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::basic_ofstream<char> >; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type = long unsigned int]’
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_vector.h:667:41:   required from ‘void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::resize(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type) [with _Tp = std::basic_ofstream<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::basic_ofstream<char> >; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type = long unsigned int]’
/mnt/c/<snip>/FileLogger.cpp:72:38:   required from here
```

I don't understand the error.  The code compiles fine under Visual Studio 2015.

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: From here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15644938/what-does-in-instantiation-of-required-from-here-mean it looks like there might be some error in code. So it'll help if you post code too.

Comment: It looks like you've missed the most important part of the error message; there should be some indication as to what the actual problem is, rather than just a backtrace. You should create a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by upgrading to g++ 5 (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS) as suggested in the comments. Thank you.